# How to get Notification content details in NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, notifications, android-remoteview

I want to get the content details of [RemoteView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) from [StatusBarNotification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification.html) while listening to [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)

How can I get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution

```
RemoteViews remoteView = statusBarNotification.getNotification().contentView;
```